# Create array formula using axlsx

Tags: ruby, array-formulas, axlsx

I'm trying to generate an Excel xlsx spreadsheet using Ruby and the AXLSX gem.  I'm new to this gem and the examples don't show more than just 'basic' formulas.

When adding a row using this code the output in the formula columns is incorrect.

```
require 'axlsx'

numRows = 10

p = Axlsx::Package.new
wb = p.workbook
wb.add_worksheet(:name => "Formula") do |ws|
  date_style = wb.styles.add_style :sz => 9, :font_name => 'Calibri' #, :format_code => 'mm/dd/yyyy'

  # add rows with random values, the current day, and 3 empty cells to be populated with formulas
  ws.add_row ["Data 1", "Data 2", "Data 3", 'Today', 'Reference', 'Sum', 'Array Formula 1', 'Array Formula 2']
  numRows.times { |i| ws.add_row [rand(100), rand(200), rand(50), '=TODAY()', '', '', '', ''] }

  (1..10).each { |i|
    ws.rows[i].cells[3].type = :string
    ws.rows[i].cells[4].value = "=A#{i+1}"
    ws.rows[i].cells[5].value = "=SUM(A#{i+1}:C#{i+1})"
    ws.rows[i].cells[6].value = "=INDEX($A$2:$A$#{numRows+1},MATCH(1,(B#{i+1}=$A$2:$A$#{numRows+1})*($C$2=$A$2:$A$#{numRows+1}),0))"
    ws.rows[i].cells[7].value = "{=INDEX($A$2:$A$#{numRows+1},MATCH(1,(B#{i+1}=$A$2:$A$#{numRows+1})*($C$2=$A$2:$A$#{numRows+1}),0))}"
  }

  ws.cols[3].each { |c| c.style = date_style }
end

p.serialize 'test.xlsx'
```

The array formulas don't work.  As shown in the code, I've tried with and without the brackets.  I'm not sure how to indicate that the cell contents are a formula array.

Any examples available on how to do this?

Comment: any update on this ?

Comment: its present at https://github.com/randym/axlsx/pull/295